# What is the usual method to backup only specific columns in table rows with condition in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

We have multiple tables which needed to be updated on datetime columns in each, update by adding 1 hour where the datetime value between A and B.

We usually take full backup of DB, so that would be there. But we want to be able to restore only the fields which are modified.

Can we take backup of only the primary keys and the corresponding datetime columns for each table? I am able to generate SQL queries using bash scripting for taking backup into csv. But the mixed usage of SQL and bash doesnt look good. Also, some tables have composite primary keys and it is getting tricky to write script to restore from CSV. Is there any standard method where such updates are usually handled safely?

I am hoping if we could do something like this:

- Take backup of to be updated rows with primary keys and corresponding updated column in CSV.
- Perform the update ie.., add 1 hour on fields with condition

For restore:

- Restore the CSV backup to temp table. (Handle composite primary keys by using a metadata for each table while exporting CSV to temp table)
- Update main tables for every row in temp table using primary keys and value from corresponding column in temp table.

But my only concern is the mixed use of bash and sql. If that is what people generally do, then I would stick to this (or may be use python and SQL).

Comment: *I am hoping if we could do something like this:* The scheme is workable. Do not forget that triggers may interfere if exists. *I am able to generate SQL queries using bash scripting for taking backup into csv. But the mixed usage of SQL and bash doesnt look good.* Create stored procedure(s) and use CLI or any client/script/program for SP call..

Comment: Blanket changing of a column (by, say, adding an hour) sounds like a poor schema design.  Can the date be stored _once_ in some other place?